# Evaluation inside Compile

Tags: evaluation, compile

here's a simple question:

I have a function:

```
Compile[{T, μ, dq, ω, m}, 
 Module[{s = 0.0 + 0.0 I, mu = -10*T}, 
  Do[s = s + 0.1*T*(expr), {mu, -10.0 T, 10.0 T, 0.1 T}]; s], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

where `expr` is some long expression assigned before.  I cannot make this work other that manually copy-pasting an explicit long expression for expr.  I tried `Evaluate` and some combinations of `ReleaseHold`,   but it did not work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True}` to your `Compile`. [CompilationOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem!